# Redirect to login page when umbraco site loads

Tags: umbraco

What I want to know is how to redirect the user to the login page, when the website loads. Or if this cant be done, how to change the default page of the website.

when looking for an answer on the internet, i found several solutions mentioning 'nodes' in the content tab. But I have a template installed, and below the content folder, is the 
'Business Site' folder which came with my template.
Thanks,

Callum

Comment: Is this a member (front-end user) or an umbraco user (cms editor)? If the "site" loads, do you mean when umbraco shows the splash page? Or when loading a "page"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a whole Umbraco site to require a login set all the pages to restrict their access in the content of the Admin section. In the content section click right on the pages you want to restrict access to and select Public Access.

Child pages will inherit the public access settings from their parents so to restrict access to the whole site select your top home page. When setting the public access restrictions you will be asked for the login and error pages you want to use, so these will need to have been created before hand.

I've just tested this on my Umbraco 6 site, I don't know about other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking here.

http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/sydney-web-design-umbraco-reserved-properties-and-their-usage

Are you redirecting them to the umbraco backend? Or is the entire site you want protected?

Another good resource is Umbraco TV specifically the role based protection video.